# Do local cURL requests make a change on my allowed Bandwidth count?

Tags: curl, hosting, localhost, server-side, bandwidth

For instance: I have a purchased a hosting that allows me 10 GB's of monthly transfer bandwidth.

Will this 10 GB's of transfer be affected if I make some cURL requests, from-a-script-to-a-script on the same server (in this case it's a kind of "local-request")?

Comment: I bet it counts towards your monthly quota! Although your question is not clear at all, it depends on a lot of things.

Comment: clearified: do cURL request from index.php to index2.php, internally, affect on my monthly bandwidth usage? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only outbound traffic affects your bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your service provider!
Also your question would be better answered at http://serverfault.com

Comment: aren't you supposed to be :P Ali, like the Muhammed boxer? :Pq